# Unfriendly Numbers from Interviewstreet.com

Tags: c#

The problem is as follows:

```
There is one friendly number and N unfriendly numbers. We want to find how many numbers are there which exactly divide the friendly number, but does not divide any of the unfriendly numbers.

Input Format:
The first line of input contains two numbers N and K seperated by spaces. N is the number of unfriendly numbers, K is the friendly number.
The second line of input contains N space separated unfriendly numbers.

Output Format:
Output the answer in a single line.

Constraints:
1 <= N <= 10^6
1 <= K <= 10^13
1 <= unfriendly numbers <= 10^18

Sample Input:
8 16
2 5 7 4 3 8 3 18

Sample Output:
1

Explanation :
Divisors of the given friendly number 16, are { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 } and the unfriendly numbers are {2, 5, 7, 4, 3, 8, 3, 18}. Now 1 divides all unfriendly numbers, 2 divide 2, 4 divide 4, 8 divide 8 but 16 divides none of them. So only one number exists which divide the friendly number but does not divide any of the unfriendly numbers. So the answer is 1.
```

Following is my C# solution:

```
class Solution
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string firstLine = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] firstLineItems = firstLine.Split(' ');

        ulong friendlyNum = Convert.ToUInt64(firstLineItems[1]);
        int noOfunf = Convert.ToInt32(firstLineItems[0]);

        string secondLine = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] secondLineItems = secondLine.Split(' ');

        List<ulong> unfriendlyNumbersArray = new List<ulong>(noOfunf);

        foreach (string str in secondLineItems)
        {
            unfriendlyNumbersArray.Add(Convert.ToUInt64(str));
        }

        List<ulong> divisors = CalculateDivisors(friendlyNum);

        Console.WriteLine(finalCall(divisors, unfriendlyNumbersArray));
    }

    private static List<ulong> CalculateDivisors(ulong number)
    {
        List<ulong> factors = new List<ulong>();

        for (ulong factor = 1; factor * factor <= number; ++factor)
        {
            if (number % factor == 0)
            {
                factors.Add(factor);
                if (factor * factor != number)
                {
                    factors.Add(number / factor);
                }
            }
        }
        return factors;
    }

    private static long finalCall(List<ulong> divisors, List<ulong> unfriendlyNumbersArray)
    {
        long output = 0;
        var unfriendlyNumbers = (from i in unfriendlyNumbersArray select i).Distinct();

        foreach (ulong divisor in divisors)
        {
            var test = unfriendlyNumbers.Where(number => number % divisor == 0).ToList();
            output += (test.Count == 0) ? 1 : 0;
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

Only first 3 test cases pass. 4th one is killed, 5th and 6th one gives me parsing exception for string.

Exception for 5th and 6th ones:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in the correct format
    at System.UInt64.Parse (System.String s) [0x00000] in :0 
    at System.Convert.ToUInt64 (System.String value) [0x00000] in :0 
    at Solution.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0 
    [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.FormatException: Input string was not in the     correct format
    at System.UInt64.Parse (System.String s) [0x00000] in :0 
    at System.Convert.ToUInt64 (System.String value) [0x00000] in :0 
    at Solution.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0
```

Comment: You should try to debug this yourself first; step through; at the point it errors (one of the Convert.ToUInt64), what is the input? i.e. what is `str` or `firstLineItems[1]` (depending on where the exception happens). Debug first, **then** ask...

Comment: Hi Marc, I agree with you completely. However I do not have input with me. These test cases are not shared in interviewstreet.com. That is why I had to ask this question so bluntly. Sorry for that.

Comment: yes, but if *you* can't debug it because you don't have the data, why do you expect us to *invent* the failing data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem based on the following [link](http://bababadalgharaghtakamminarronnkonnbro.blogspot.in/2012/05/numbers-are-friends-not-food.html).
I was really amazed by the in-depth understanding of number theory  of the author of the above link.
There is nothing wrong in the above algorithm. just that it will not solve the problem within  5 seconds, the constraint which we we have abide by.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the overload of `Split` which takes a `StringSplitOptions` parameter and pass `RemoveEmptyEntries`. Otherwise, if the input is separated by multiple spaces, the array contains empty strings, which cannot be parsed.